# How can I use a JavaScript function in a Angular TypeScript component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I wrote a function like this:

```
function clean() {
fsExtra.remove(sumoDir)
}
```

in a file named `commands.js`

I export this function in this way:

```
module.exports = {[...], clean: clean, [...]}
```

I need to call this function in an Angular TypeScript component that i used for my frontend.

First of all I created a module with

> ng g m home

next I import my function in `home.module.ts` in this way:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import * as commands from './../../../src/commands.js'


@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [
CommonModule
]
})
export class HomeModule { }
export {commands}
```

And I imported it in my `home.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatCheckboxChange} from "@angular/material/checkbox";
import {commands} from "./home.module"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
      })

 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  [...]
async clean(){
}
[...]
}
```

When I do a `ng build` the outpur is:

```
Warning: [...]/home.component.css exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 kB was not met by 1.31 kB with a total of 3.31 kB.



Error: node_modules/recursive-copy/index.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Stats } from 'fs';
                        ~~~~


Error: node_modules/recursive-copy/index.d.ts:2:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'stream'. '[...]node_modules/stream/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try npm i --save-dev @types/stream if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'stream';

2 import { Stream } from 'stream';
```

How can I fix it? or How can I import correctly my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but you are trying to use the [`recursive-copy`](https://github.com/timkendrick/recursive-copy) library in Angular while it is designed for Node.js. Angular runs in the browser and there is no API such as `fs` in the browser because it has no access to the machine's filesystem.

Comment: If I don't write the import line of my function `import {commands} from "./home.module"` my app works and I don't have any problems with 'fs' or 'stream'

Comment: Yes because unused code gets evicted from the compiled bundle

Comment: Ok, but I don't really understand how can I solve the problem. I only need to use functions of my JavaScript backend with my Angular frontend. How can I implement this?

Comment: Expose that function as an HTTP endpoint, then call it with Angular's `HttpClient` service

Comment: I can't modify the JavaScript backend, my work consist in write an Angular frontend for an app that has only a CLI.

Comment: Are you sure of the feasability? An Angular app cannot interact with the machine, it can only send HTTP requests. If you don't have a backend that accepts HTTP requests then what you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: You could develop a small backend as a middleware to expose HTTP endpoints and execute commands.